# How can I embed native Browser applications in Java/J2ee web application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web, browser

I want to embed a browser within a Java Web application. The use case is :  A browser icon is displayed in my jsp/jsf page. When i click on the icon it should open a browser window . I tried some third party applications like 'Lobo,Dj  native, etc. but all of these are for desktop applications?
Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: You might open a web page in a new window, but the thing that requests and displays the results of a JSP/JSF page ***is-a*** web-browser.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch , Hi, Is it possible to inline a web browser within a web browser , something like "Citrix" , which can launch applications on our behalf in a session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to inline a web browser within a web browser , something like "Citrix" , which can launch applications on our behalf in a session.

Yes. You could use a [frameset tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frameset.asp) to contain frames. That might look something like

```
<frameset cols="25%,*">
  <frame src="frame_a.htm">
  <frame src="frame_b.htm">
</frameset>
```